# Sort wrapper list in Apex based on Levels

Tags: apex, list, sort

I have created a wrapper which contains an account record and a string describing the level of account `Platinum, Gold, Silver`.

```
public class PartnerWrapper implements Comparable {
    public Account acc;
    public String level;
}
```

So how can I sort this wrapper list (using `compareTo` method as I have implemented my class with `Comparable` interface) first displaying results for `Platinum`, then `Gold` and then `Silver`?

If this cannot be achieved using `Comparable` interface, then please provide sample code snippet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public class PartnerWrapper implements Comparable {
    private static final Map<String, Integer> levelsOrder = new Map<String, Integer>{
        'Platinum' => 1,
        'Gold' => 2,
        'Silver' => 3
        };
    public Account acc {get; set;}
    public String level {get; set;}

    public Integer compareTo(Object thatObj){
        PartnerWrapper that = (PartnerWrapper) thatObj;
        Integer thisOrder = defineLevelOrder(this.level);
        Integer thatOrder = defineLevelOrder(that.level);
        return thisOrder - thatOrder;
    }

    private Integer defineLevelOrder(String currentlevel){
        Integer result = 2147483647;
        if(levelsOrder.containsKey(currentlevel)){
            result = levelsOrder.get(currentlevel);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

You can control order by additional wrapper static field, that stores level and its order.

```
private static final Map<String, Integer> levelsOrder = new Map<String, Integer>{
    'Platinum' => 1,
    'Gold' => 2,
    'Silver' => 3
    };
```

Do not give field `public` access modifiers without properties, so I added properties as well.

If level is not in order defining field, than order of it is a max `Integer` apex value `2147483647`. So unknown `level` values would be last after sorting

Comment: Since you're already doing Integer values, you could have simply said: `return thisOrder - thatOrder;` instead of all that if-else logic. It's not strictly required that you return -1, 0, and 1, just a negative value, 0 value, or positive value.

Comment: @sfdcfox you are exactly right. I've updated code, thanks!

Comment: Well, this really seems some interesting stuff. It is working as described by Alexander, but I really need to understand the logic behind this in deep. Thanks man.